# Mathematica 3D plot with the x and y axis coordinates in separate lists

Tags: list, 3d, wolfram-mathematica

I have a (i x j) sized matrix `mat` which contains values from an experiment.

If I use `ListPlot3D[mat]`  I can visualise this in a 3D plot.

I also have two arrays of size i (`aRow`) and of size j (`aCol`) which I determined from my experiment.

How do I replace the default x and y axis shown with `ListPlot3D[mat]` with `aRow` and `aCol`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html) option and it example uses in the docs.

---

Here's one way to do it.  First generate some example data:

```
mat = Table[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2, .1}, {y, -2, 2, .1}];    
aCol = aRow = Round[mat[[20]], 0.01];
```

Plot it in 3D.  I chose to show every 10th tick mark out of all possible ones.  `list[[;; ;; 10]]` selects every 10th element of a list.

```
ListPlot3D[mat,
 Ticks -> {
   Transpose[{Range@Length[aRow], aRow}][[;; ;; 10]],
   Transpose[{Range@Length[aCol], aCol}][[;; ;; 10]],
   Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plot it in 2D too. `ListDensityPlot` has a `Frame` (not `Axes`) by default, so we use `FrameTicks`

```
ListDensityPlot[mat,
 FrameTicks -> {
   Transpose[{Range@Length[aRow], aRow}][[;; ;; 10]],
   Transpose[{Range@Length[aCol], aCol}][[;; ;; 10]],
   None, None},
 Mesh -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Update**

If you don't need arbitrary ticks, just a different range for the usual, linearly spaces tick marks, then you can use the `DataRange` option like this:

```
ListPlot3D[mat, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you still need the data in an `{x,y,z}` format (because the coordinates are not evenly spaced), you can build it using

```
Join @@ MapThread[Append, {Outer[List, aRow, aCol], mat}, 2]
```

Comment: This is good however I would to control the tick spacing in accordance to the default I would have got without using ticks.

Comment: I assumed this could be done by using the "Transpose" command on the data itself in some way. EDIT:I meant Transpose

Comment: @akk To my knowledge there is no way to retrieve the auto-generated tick marks (`AbsoluteOptions[graphics, Ticks]` returns `Automatic`). I remember trying to do this a long time ago, but I failed.  You have to come up with your own algorithm to find a tick density.

Comment: The ticks would be automatic by using the Transpose command such that (z11, z12, z21, z22); (x1, x2, x3); (y1, y2, y3), becomes --> (x1, y1, z11), (x1, y2, z12), (x2, y1, z21) if you follow. Not sure how to do this though.

Comment: @akk I'm not sure I understand what you are saying.  I cannot access the tickmarks Mathematica generates by default.  I can't tell it will choose `{10,20,30,40}` and show my own marks at the same place.

Comment: I mean that the tick command is not needed. I would have though it possible to only use ListPlot3D[mat] where mat is a three dimensional list where elements are {x1, y1, z11}, {x1, y2, z12}, {x2, y1, z21}, {x2, y2, z22}

Comment: @akk I think I understand now.  Please see my update to the answer.

Comment: You can get the automatically generated tick marks using `Options[graphics,Ticks]`. For some reason `AbsoluteOptions` flakes out with ticks of all sorts.

Comment: @Eli For what kind of graphics does that work for you?  I never get anything else than `Automatic` with `Options` (2D or 3D).  I get the values with `AbsoluteOptions` for all 2D graphics I tried, but not 3D ones.

Comment: Usually 2D graphics. Although, now that I think about it, it's usually `FrameTicks`, not the regular ones (I think `Frame`d plots generally look better than `Axes`ed ones.

Comment: Also, I highly recommend the [CustomTicks](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/) package for more control over `Ticks` of all sorts.

Answer (score 2):

If the differences between consecutive elements in `aRow` and `bRow` are constant, you could do something like

```
ListPlot3D[mat, DataRange -> (Through[{Min, Max}[#]] & /@ {aCol, aRow})]
```

If not then you could create a list with elements `{aCol[[i]], aRow[[j]], mat[[j,i]]}` and plot that. There are different ways to do this, for example

```
list = Flatten[Table[{aCol[[i]], aRow[[j]], mat[[j, i]]}, 
    {i, Length[aCol]}, {j, Length[aRow]}], 1];

ListPlot3D[list]
```

**Edit**

A faster way to create `list` is to do something like

```
list = ConstantArray[0, {Length[aCol] Length[aRow], 3}];
list[[All, {2, 1}]] = Tuples[{aRow, aCol}];
list[[All, 3]] = Flatten[mat];
```